# What is the taquito way of building a lambda?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

So, this is the piece of code in my smartpy test contracts. Both methods, calc_reward and updateLogic is working. This is in the test section of the contract.

[image]

So, basically, what I want to do is call the updateLogic method from taquito but how would I build lambda for it?

After much hassle, I was able to pack/unpack values similar to sp.pack in taquito but I'm again stuck in the updating part.

[image]

Is it not possible? Or, do I have a wrong understanding?

Here's the entire code of smart contract:

```
import smartpy as sp

class Testes(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.init(**kwargs)
        
    @sp.entry_point
    def calc_reward(self, data):
        self.data.value = self.data.logic(data)
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def updateLogic(self, logic):
        self.data.logic = logic
    
@sp.add_test("Testes contract test")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario.h1("Testing upgradability")
    
    def logic1(data):
        t = sp.TRecord(x=sp.TNat, y=sp.TNat)
        unpacked = sp.unpack(data, t).open_some(message="Can't unpack sed!!")
        
        sp.result(unpacked.x + unpacked.y)
    
    def logic2(data):
        t = sp.TRecord(x=sp.TNat, y=sp.TNat, z=sp.TNat)
        unpacked = sp.unpack(data, t).open_some(message="Can't unpack sed!!")
        
        sp.result(unpacked.x + unpacked.y)
    
    
    c1 = Testes(value=100, logic=sp.build_lambda(logic1))
    scenario+=c1
    
    # Using logic 1
    scenario += c1.calc_reward(sp.pack(sp.record(x=1, y=2)))
    
      # Update logic to version 2
    scenario += c1.updateLogic(sp.build_lambda(logic2))

    # Use logic version 2
    scenario += c1.calc_reward(sp.pack(sp.record(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)))
    
    sp.add_compilation_target("testes", Testes(value=69, logic=sp.build_lambda(logic1)))
```

And here's my typescript file:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import { InMemorySigner } from "@taquito/signer";
import { TezosToolkit } from "@taquito/taquito";
import { NETWORK } from "../config/config";
import {
  MichelsonData,
  MichelsonType,
  packDataBytes,
} from "@taquito/michel-codec";

dotenv.config();

const { ORIGINATOR_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

const signer = await InMemorySigner.fromSecretKey(ORIGINATOR_PRIVATE_KEY!);
const Tezos = new TezosToolkit(NETWORK.GHOSTNET.url);
Tezos.setProvider({ signer: signer });

const updateContract = async () => {
    //idk what to do here
};

const updateValue = () => {
  const data: MichelsonData = {
    prim: "Pair",
    args: [{ int: "111" }, { int: "222" }],
  };

  const typ: MichelsonType = {
    prim: "pair",
    args: [{ prim: "int" }, { prim: "int" }],
  };

  const packed = packDataBytes(data, typ);
  console.log(packed.bytes);

  Tezos.contract
    .at("KT1AbLHMuiKaSufWo5MzU5pQGwx7BayQNLUf")
    .then((contract) => {
      return contract.methods.calc_reward(packed.bytes).send();
    })
    .then((op) => {
      console.log(`Waiting for ${op.hash} to be confirmed...`);
      return op.confirmation(1).then(() => op.hash);
    })
    .then((hash: any) => console.log("Done!"))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda is just a piece of Michelson code, you will have to provide the Michelson code to Taquito before packing it and sending it as a parameter to the contract entrypoint.
You can find an example in [this draft](https://hackmd.io/l6OByy_rSSqQaJWKfxcRlQ#Using-the-transfer-entrypoint) for the upcoming multisig documentation in Taquito.

Comment: Is there a way to get michelson code from a python function? 

```
import smartpy as sp

def logic(data):
    t = sp.TRecord(x=sp.TNat, y=sp.TNat, z=sp.TNat)
    unpacked = sp.unpack(data, t).open_some(message="Can't unpack sed!!")
    
    sp.result(unpacked.x + unpacked.y)
    
ans = sp.build_lambda(logic)
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: There might be a way to compile a SmartPy expression into Michelson (there is one in Ligo) but I don't know SmartPy so I can't answer that, sorry. You should try to ask on the SmartPy Telegram channel.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Claude Barde